# Where is House Ordos in the 2021 movie Dune?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

Back in the 90s, I used the play the *Dune 2* RTS computer game, and I recall there being three houses: Atreides (blue), Harkonnen (red) and Ordos (green) (along with an unplayable Emperor).  But in the recent (2021) movie *Dune*, I didn't notice any mention of House Ordos.  So...

**Question**: Where is House Ordos in the 2021 movie Dune?

Note that I've never actually read the books, just played the game and watched the movie.

Comment: Just behind that big pile of sand over there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Eaten by a passing sandworm?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think you'll find that's a dune.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In short, [House Ordos](https://neoencyclopedia.fandom.com/wiki/House_Ordos) was an invention of the (non-canon) Dune Encyclopaedia. It was mentioned in a few of the games, notably *Dune II* but also *Dune 2000* and *Battle For Dune* as a third faction intended to give you the option of playing someone other than the Atreides and Harkonnen families, but it doesn't appear in any of the original or follow-on novels.

The film makers seems to have made efforts to remain true to the original Frank Herbert novel(s) without bringing in non-canon elements from other properties.

> “They’re very protective of their father and grandfather’s work,” Roth
> says of the Herbert family. “But **everybody was so true to the book.
> Nobody was going to try to do something that flipped it on its head.”**
> (Brian was unavailable to comment for this story but told an
> interviewer for the website Inverse last year that Villeneuve’s film
> “will forever be considered the definitive film adaptation” of his
> father’s novel.)
>
> <sub><sup>https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/movies/story/2021-08-24/dune-screenwriters-adaptation-novel</sup></sub>

Comment: How odd that they should be so keen to have a non-canonical third faction, and then in Command & Conquer, where they had no canon to adhere to, they were happy with just two.

Comment: @IMSoP - ***Who came up with the idea of House Ordos? It is mentioned in the Dune Encyclopedia but not in the novels or movie and is something we have never known for sure.*** - *We wanted to have a third side and there wasn't a compelling and suitable one available from the movie. I think Marc Cram (producer) came up with the idea to use Ordos and we decided to give them the sneaky and devious character.* - https://forum.dune2k.com/topic/1899-joe-bostic-interview/

Comment: @Valorum Ah yes. Sneaky and devious, in contrast to the other great houses.

Comment: [“They’re very protective of their father and grandfather’s work,” Roth says of the Herbert family.]  Are they talking about the same Brian Herbert we know?